# How to add a value of a variable in a sqlite database existing column?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sql-update, android-sqlite

I would like to ask for some help with my android code. I am trying to develop a quiz app using SQLite.My Database has two Tables. One for Students Information and one for the Questions and answers. Students Information such as Name, Student ID e.c. are inputs through textViews . After taking the Quiz in the Result activity the Score shown up. But i also want this score to be kept in a column COLUMN_SCORE of Student_trable.

I tried to update the table using this method:

```
 `public static void addScore (int StudentScore){

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(DataContract.StudentTable.COLUMN_SCORE, StudentScore);

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM student_info ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 " ,null);

    db.update(DataContract.StudentTable.TABLE_NAME1, cv, DataContract.StudentTable.COLUMN_SCORE +  "= ?", new String[] {String.valueOf (c)});
    db.close();`
```

but i failed. Any suggestion please?
Here is some more details of my code:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery in the `WHERE` clause argument of the `update()` method, so that there is no need for a `SELECT` query to retrieve the last `id`:

```
public static void addScore(int studentScore) {
    String table = DataContract.StudentTable.TABLE_NAME1;
    String id = DataContract.StudentTable.COLUMN_ID;

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(DataContract.StudentTable.COLUMN_SCORE, studentScore);
    db.update(
        table, 
        cv, 
        id + " = (SELECT MAX(" + id + ") FROM " + table + ")", 
        null
    );
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: Good point but i  can't use id as an argument in method addScore in the Class from where i call the method...It's too complicated. I have to call  id inside   addscore. Thats why  i thought that  i could pick it from the table internally...

Comment: @fotonio one way or another you have to use the id. What makes no sense is the SELECT query.

Comment: I was trying to find a way to pick the last id of the table ..

Comment: @fotonio why the last id?

Comment: Because the last player dont know his position at the table so he has an unknown id

Comment: @fotonio is this what you are trying to do? Update only the last row of the table? Don't you want to be able to update any row of the table?

Comment: Yes, every time to update the last row of the table...

Comment: @fotonio you do not mention this in your question. Check my edited answer.

Comment: It works perfectly!! Thank you!!